# Encrypt Password with EncryptByPassPhrase function in sql

Tags: sql

```
alter PROC   [dbo].[Ins_Users] 
@UserID int , 
@UserName nvarchar (max) , 
@Password nvarchar (max) , 
@Name nvarchar (100) , 
@Family nchar (10) , 
@LastLoginDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
-----------------------------------------
DECLARE @Passphrase nvarchar(128);
declare @newPass nvarchar(max);
declare @temp varbinary(max);
SET @Passphrase
    = 'hadi';
SET @temp= EncryptByPassPhrase(@Passphrase,@Password);
set @newPass=CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@temp);
-----------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] 
        ( 
        [UserID], 
        [UserName], 
        [Password], 
        [Name], 
        [Family], 
        [LastLoginDate] 
        ) 
        VALUES 
        ( 
        @UserID, 
        @UserName, 
        @newPass, 
        @Name, 
        @Family, 
        @LastLoginDate 
        ) 
END
```

I want to encrypt pass befor store it in db.
I use EncryptByPassPhrase Function in sql that return a varbinary as result
but my pass columns has nvarchar type so i convert result to nvarchar by
    set @newPass=CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@temp);
when i trace it result of encryption is true but result of Convert is empty .

Comment: You can't use convert as you get an ASCII representation of varbinary values. I'm sure there will be a way, but I've written an encryption library, and it was difficult to debug even without mucking around with the data types. My advice would be to use a varbinary column, if you need to keep the varchar around for some reason then keep them both.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, see for a hack to convert the value http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_larsson/archive/2010/01/27/convert-binary-value-to-string-value.aspx, but as I say, much better to use a varbinary column and leave the convert alone.